# Biztalk install help

Tags: biztalk

I try to install Biztalk2009, with SQL 2008R2CTPNov, on Win Server 2008.
I'm blocked at the configuration step "groups" :

```
    [19:22:18 Info Configuration Framework]Configuring feature: WMI
    [19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CBtsCfg::ConfigureFeature
    [19:22:18 Info BtsCfg]  Configuring feature: WMI
    [19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CBtsCfg::IsSelectedAnswer
    [19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Leaving function: CBtsCfg::IsSelectedAnswer
    [19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::Connect
    [19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] WMI is already connected
    [19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Leaving function: CWMI::Connect
    [19:22:18 Info ConfigHelper]    NT group BizTalk Server Operators was not created because it already exists
    [19:22:18 Info ConfigHelper NetAPI Info: ] Le groupe local spécifié existe déjà.
    [19:22:18 Info ConfigHelper]    NT group BizTalk Server Administrators was not created because it already exists
    [19:22:18 Info ConfigHelper NetAPI Info: ] Le groupe local spécifié existe déjà.
    [19:22:18 Info BtsCfg] Entering function: CWMI::CreateGroup
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0527 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::PutInstance() try to acquire lock
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0539 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::PutInstance() lock acquired successfully
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0546 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::VerifyMgmtDbCompatibility(CInstance) started
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0553 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::VerifyMgmtDbCompatibility(CInstance) finished successfully
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0564 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::PutInstance(MSBTS_GroupSetting.MgmtDbName="BizTalkMgmtDb",MgmtDbServerName="ECTXEVLBZTK") started
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0572 [INFO] WMI CAdapter::ConvertWMI2Admin() started
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0581 [INFO] WMI CDataContainer::SetWCHAR() - Possible problem: item value is overwritten
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0591 [INFO] WMI CAdapter::ConvertWMI2Admin() finished with HR=0
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0611 [INFO] WMI QueryStringValue query regkey 'MgmtDBServer'
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0620 [INFO] WMI CAdmCoreGroupInst::TryCreateNewGroup() started
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0632 [INFO] WMI Creating Mgmt database...
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0641 [INFO] WMI Calling CDataSource.Open() against ECTXEVLBZTK\master
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0792 [INFO] WMI CDataSource.Open() returned
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0810 [WARN] AdminLib GetBTSMessage: hrErr=80040e1d; Msg=Error "0x80040E1D" occurred.; 
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0824 [WARN] AdminLib GetBTSMessage: hrErr=c0c02524; Msg=Failed to create Management database "BizTalkMgmtDb" on server "ECTXEVLBZTK".
    Error "0x80040E1D" occurred.; 
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0835 [ERR] WMI Failed in pAdmInst->Create() in CWMIInstProv::PutInstance(). HR=c0c02524
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0846 [ERR] WMI WMI error description is generated: Failed to create Management database "BizTalkMgmtDb" on server "ECTXEVLBZTK".
    Error "0x80040E1D" occurred.
    2010-01-14 19:22:18:0860 [INFO] WMI CWMIInstProv::PutInstance() finished. HR=c0c02524
    [19:22:18 Error BtsCfg] f:\bt\890\private\source\setup\prod\btssetup\btscfg\btswmi.cpp(358): FAILED hr = c0c02524

[19:22:18 Error BtsCfg] Failed to create Management database "BizTalkMgmtDb" on server "ECTXEVLBZTK".
Error "0x80040E1D" occurred.
```

It seems that the install can't create Managment database,
But the SSO database is created OK...

Has someone a clue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Using SQL Server 2008 R2 is not currently supported in any edition of BizTalk, and very likely it doesn't work at all. Official support for SQL2K8R2 is expected as part of [BizTalk 2009 R2](http://www.microsoft.com/biztalk/en/us/roadmap.aspx#2009r2) later this year.

Comment: I hit this too, what a shame.  One wouldn't think R2 releases would change things so much.

Comment: Also, I just confirmed that BT2009/R2 is now called BT2010, and the Beta is available today (as of Aug 2010).